# Variable Staying Static

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, coroutine

I am encountering an issue with a variable `gems` in my code. `gems` is not increasing like it is supposed to. First, I thought there was something forcing the variable to stay at zero, but this is the only place we use the gems variable.

```
...
private float gems = GameCtrl.instance.gems; //IN GAMECTRL SCRIPT: public float gems = 0.0f;
float gemsInc = 0.1f;

private void Start(){
    ...
    StartCoroutine(IncrementGems());
}

...

IEnumerator IncrementGems() { //GOAL every 10 sec increment gems by 0.1
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        gems += gemsInc;
        Debug.Log(gems); // output: 0
        gemAmount.text = "x" + gems; //output: "x0"
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I have tried debugging. However, the output of the debug is 0. The goal of the above code is to increase the `gems` value by `gemsInc` (0.1) every 10 seconds but it is not working.
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

[NOTE the `...` signifies that there is more unrelated code and is not in the actual script itself]

Comment: Is gemsInc actually 0.1?

Comment: Like @shingo said, you should add a `Debug.Log` for `gemsInc` before incrementing to check that it's value is actually 0.1f

Comment: Also what is comming to mind is, is `GameCtrl.instance.gems` also float and not int and/or where `gems` will be assigned again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes bugs can occur in other places of the code where you dont expect. So the bug in your code might happen somewhere else.
Or, could it be that since you have yield wait for 10 seconds, and you didn't wait for 10 second and thought it didn't work on play?

Anyway, here's another way of doing it without the coroutine:

```
    [SerializeField] private float gemsCount = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gemsIncrement = 0.1f;
    
    private float timer = 0f;
    private const float timerMax = 10f; // every 10 seconds


    private void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime; 
        
        if (timer >= timerMax)
        {
            timer = 0f;
            gemsCount += gemsIncrement;
            Debug.Log("Gems: " + gemsCount);
        }
    }
```

And as usual, you have to wait for 10 seconds before you see the first gemCount increase.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found something. The GameCtrl object is actually NOT in the scene the gems are at. So I believe that since it doesn't have access to the GameCtrl object, the variable doesn't increment properly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As a counter-example, I was able to add this script to a game object in a brand-new project and it correctly outputs incrementing debug log messages once per second.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float gems = 0.0f;
    float gemsInc = 0.1f;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(IncrementGems());
    }

    IEnumerator IncrementGems()
    {
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            gems += gemsInc;
            Debug.Log(gems);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Unity log messages appear correctly]

<sup>2021.3.23.f1</sup>

Any problems you are having are likely external to the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and suggestions! Now the gem variable is incrementing properly without any issue..